# How do I play rtmp streams with JW Player?

Tags: javascript, streaming, jwplayer, rtmp

I want to know how to stream RTMP with JW Player I just begun this, the embed didnt help so if someone can share a code that works for him, would be helpful.

Comment: When you say that the "Embed didn't help" what do you mean? Do you have a piece of code that you are working with but are unable to make it work? Can you please be a little more specific?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We have a guide here for this - http://www.longtailvideo.com/support/jw-player/28854/using-rtmp-streaming

And an example - http://www.longtailvideo.com/support/jw-player/29395/rtmp-single-stream

Comment: what to do if I want HD option that provides toggling in video quality? smil file configuration not works for me

Comment: This answer is a pure example of why link only answers are terrible

Comment: RTMP is a deprecated Flash technology at this point. The answer was from 5 years ago. Thanks for bumping that up.